# Print the "multiple functions output" [not just printing Strings] in same line in Python

Tags: python-3.x, function, object, printing, output

So I am trying to print Multiple functions output in a same line , not the strings, I know we could use end=" in python 3.0 and above but this is different scenario,I tried to Iterate over the functions but of avail , I have been trying but I wanna get an idea on how to approach towards this, I am still a beginner so anything helps and also  please check my code and Sample output

```
class Costco:

 def __init__(self,n):
   self.n=n

 def letterC(self):
  print('*'*self.n)
  for i in range(self.n-2):
    print('*')
  print('*'*self.n)



 def letterO(self):
  print('*'*self.n)
  for i in range(self.n-2):
    print('*'+' '*(self.n-2)+'*')
  print('*'*self.n)


 def letterS(self):
  print('*'*self.n)
  for i in range(int(self.n/2)):
    print('*')
  print('*'*self.n)
  for i in range(int(self.n/2)):
    print(' '*(self.n-1)+'*')
  print('*'*self.n)


 def letterT(self):
  print('*'*self.n)
  for i in range(self.n-1):
    print(' '*int(self.n/2)+'*')


c1=Costco(int(input('please enter an odd number:\n')))
while c1.n%2==0:
   print('you entered an even number,please enter only odd number')
   c1=Costco(int(input('please enter an odd number:\n')))

def cost(c1):
  for i in [c1.letterC,c1.letterO,c1.letterS,c1.letterT,c1.letterC,c1.letterO]:
    i()


cost(c1)
```

so the sample output look like

```
please enter an odd number:
7
*******
*
*
*
*
*
*******
*******
*     *
*     *
*     *
*     *
*     *
*******
*******
*
*
*
*******
      *
      *
      *
*******
*******
   *
   *
   *
   *
   *
   *
*******
*
*
*
*
*
*******
*******
*     *
*     *
*     *
*     *
*     *
*******
```

But I want More like in a single line 
like

```
COSTCO
```

but not

```
C
O
S
T
C
O
```

Answer (score 0):

That print function inserts a line break at the end of whatever you're asking it to print, so every time so call print(), you will end up moving one layer lower. A way to deal with this would be to store each character as an array of strings, each containing the row you want to print.

so C[0] would be "*******" and c[1] would be "*      " and c[6] would be "******"

Then use a for loop to print each layer of the characters one at a time, inserting a white space character in between each component. kinda like print(c[i]+o[i]+s[i]+t[i]+c[i]+o[i])

The only catch is you would have to define each of the characters layer by layer beforehand and also change the way you're printing the 'S' so that it has the same number of layers as the rest of the characters.